# Python Error - int object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

The below code gives me the error, other than changing the module that plays the (winsound) sound, this worked fine on Python2.6 on Windows. Not sure where I have gone wrong on this one. This is being run on a Linux box, previously on a Windows machine. The version on Windows was 2.6 and version on Linux is 2.7.3.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "CallsWaiting.py", line 9,
>   in 
>       first_time = time.time() AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'time'

```
import _mysql
import sys
import time
import os
import pygame
pygame.init()

time = 3
first_time = time.time()
last_time = first_time

while True:
    pass
    new_time = time.time()
    if new_time - last_time > timeout:
        last_time = new_time
        os.system('cls')
        iswaiting = 0

        print "Calls Waiting: "

        con = _mysql.connect(host='oip-prod', port=3308, user='admin', passwd='1234', db='axpdb')

        con.query("select callswaiting from callcenterinformation where date - date(now()) and skillid = 2 order by time desc limit 1;")
        result = con.user_result()
        iswaiting = int('',join(result.fetch_row() [0]))

        print "%s" % \
            iswaiting

        if iswaiting > 0:
            print "Calls are waiting!"
            pygame.mixer.init()
            sounda = pygame.mixer,Sound("ring2.wav")
            sounda.play()
```

Comment: Thanks to all, simple variable name mistake... still learning thanks all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As `time = 3` is declared as an integer,
`time.time` doesn't have any sense since time is `int` variable (that isn't a class but a primitive data type). I suppose that you expected to call `time` (module) writing `time` but, since you're redefining it as an integer, this last definition shadows the `time` module

Change `time` variable name to something else, like `myTime`

#### Error messages are usefull, you should read them. Often the answer is contained directly into this errors/warning messages

Comment: @user2659890: don't worry but before posting please explore if other users already asked something similar (this probably isn't the case as it is such a basic question) or read some documentation on the internet. Cheers and enjoy S.O. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have variable time:

```
time = 3
```

and you have previously imported package time:

```
import time
```

When you try to do

```
time.time()
```

it seems that you try to call method time() of variable time (that contains int).

You should rename it and it will figure out conflicts with package name.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `time` variable. While `time` is module imported from `import` statement. So when you access `time.x` its try to access variable instead of `module`.

Change variable name or import module `time` as another name.