# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'timetuple'

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-huey

Quick note: this error may be somewhat linked to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066426/python-error-int-object-has-no-attribute), but the use case and python version (the other one is still at v2) is different. Other similar threads don't regard specifically to python `datetime`.

I have the following code:

```py
import datetime
from .models import RaceData, RacerData

@periodic_task(crontab(minute='*/15'))
def record_racedata():
    team = nitrotype.Team('PR2W')
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()  # timestamp 
    
    for members in team.data["members"]:
        rcd = RaceData(
            timestamp=timestamp,
        )
        rcd.save()

@periodic_task(crontab(minute='*/15'))
def record_racerdata():
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()  # timestamp 
    
    for members in team.data["members"]:
        rcrd = RacerData(
            timestamp=timestamp,
        )
        rcrd.save()  # error comes from here
```

models:

```py
class RaceData(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    timestamp = UnixDateTimeField()

class RacerData(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    timestamp = UnixDateTimeField()
```

And I get the following output:

```sh
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'timetuple'
```

What confuses me the most is how the first inclusion of `timestamp` doesn't come with an error, but maybe the execution doesn't go from top to bottom.

Either way, I believe that I've initialized the `timestamp` variable appropriately. Can anyone please help? *Note that I cannot define `timestamp` outside either function because I need the timestamp to be constantly updated with the periodically-called functions.*

**EDIT** I've seen elsewhere that this error occurred because the namespace `datetime` was used elsewhere in the code, but this is not the case in my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a problem with the dependency that I'm using (`UnixDateTimeField`) as the error thrown out was pointed toward the package in my virtual environment.

I resorted to store the time in an integer field:

```py
import datetime
from .models import RaceData, RacerData

@periodic_task(crontab(minute='*/15'))
def record_racedata():
    team = nitrotype.Team('PR2W')
    timestamp = datetime.now().timestamp() # converts datetime into unix
    
    for members in team.data["members"]:
        rcd = RaceData(
            timestamp=timestamp,
        )
        rcd.save()

@periodic_task(crontab(minute='*/15'))
def record_racerdata():
    timestamp = datetime.now().timestamp()
    
    for members in team.data["members"]:
        rcrd = RacerData(
            timestamp=timestamp,
        )
        rcrd.save()  # error comes from here
```

models:

```py
class RaceData(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    timestamp = IntegerField()

class RacerData(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    timestamp = IntegerField()
```

Any solution is still welcome, but after browsing several other questions on SO, I came to the solution that it's the simplest to store a UNIX timestamp as an integer.  You can always convert an integer back to `datetime` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744775/how-to-convert-integer-timestamp-to-python-datetime), assuming that the initial UNIX timestamp is validated.

Still, thanks to everyone that tried to answer the question.